# MAX Result of multpiple results from INDEX and MATCH

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array, lookup

I am working with 3 columns, fname, lname, & date. Where there will be multiple duplicates of fname and lname. I am trying to write an INDEX & MATCH that will display the MAX result or the most current date:

*(in short I have a list of individuals with the First name in Column A, Last Name in Column B, and an event for that individual in column C, each individual will have multiple events, I need to write a function that will display each individual most recent event date)*

I tried with no luck, result #VALUE:

**{=MAX(INDEX(Alphabetical!$A$2:$C$178,MATCH(A2&B2,Alphabetical!$A$2:$A$178&Alphabetical!$B$2:$B$178,0),3))}**

Comment: Do you want to get the result as shown in the following picture? https://imgur.com/a/Xk0UKjN Please try the MAX formula: **=TEXT(MAX((Sheet1!A$2:A$9&Sheet1!B$2:B$9=E2&F2)*Sheet1!C$2:C$9),"e-m-d")**

Comment: Thanks, this does returns the values I want, but since it's in a text format I am unable to sort the results by date, is there a way to have it format as a short date so I can sort it?

Comment: Yes,you can change the e-m-d to the date format you want.